# why my dataset doesn't stop even if I set dataset.repeat(1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, iterator, dataset

I have a training dataset and a test dataset,

```
#training dataset
dataset_train = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(files_train)
dataset_train = dataset_train.map(...)
dataset_train = dataset_train.shuffle(...)
dataset_train = dataset_train.batch(...)
dataset_train = dataset_train.repeat(1)
iterator_train = dataset_train.make_initializable_iterator()

#test dataset
dataset_test = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(files_test)
dataset_test = dataset_test.map(...)
dataset_test = dataset_test.shuffle(...)
dataset_test = dataset_test.batch(...)
dataset_test = dataset_test.repeat(...)
iterator_test = dataset_test.make_initializable_iterator()

#for switch between two datasets.
handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(handle, dataset_train.output_types, dataset_train.output_shapes)
image_batch, label_batch = iterator.get_next()
```

and in session, I have:

```
# in tf.Session()
train_iterator_handle = sess.run(train_iterator.string_handle())
val_iterator_handle = sess.run(test_iterator.string_handle())
sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()])

#start training, switch to training dataset
sess.run(iterator_train.initializer) 
while True:
    try:
        sess.run([train_step, ...])

        if global_step % N == 0: # test
            #start test, switch to test dataset
            sess.run(iterator_test.initializer)
            while True:
                try:
                    sess.run([acc_update, ...])
                except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                    print("test finished")
                    break
            #test finished, switch back to training dataset
            sess.run(iterator_train.initializer) 
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        print("training finished")
        break
```

I read from API of TF that **the training dataset iterator can continue from where it left last time**, and I think training dataset should stop when iterated all data because I use:

```
dataset_train = dataset_train.repeat(1)
```

But actually, **my program runs and doesn't stop.**
So I think I must have made a serious mistake somewhere. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line after validation `sess.run(iterator_train.initializer)` will reset your train generator state, so it will continue reading from start. I suppose, that `N` is less that number of steps in train iterator, so it won't stop

In case you just want to continue training after validation, do not call train iterator initializer again